# Find minimum value from multiple regularly spaced columns in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have the following problem I need to address:
I have quotations from multiple vendors for multiple types of products. I need to find the product wise minimum and 2nd lowest quotations. The sheet looks somewhat like this:

[image]

I want the output in the following format:

[image]

**Now, the problem is that the number of vendors is 300**, and using the regular formula: `min(number1,number2,number3,...)` is very tedious and error prone as I have to manually click each entry for each vendor like `min(B3,F3,I3,... 300 entries)` for product 1.

**Another problem is for 2nd Lowest Quote** Here, excel does not accept discontinuous array like min function. Which means I cannot enter the formula `small(B3,F3,I3,2)` as it gives **you have entered too many arguments** error in this case.

I need to find some way to get around this problem. Please help me out with this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LibxM.png)

You could try an array formula like so:

```
=MIN(IF($B$2:$J$2=K$2,$B3:$J3))
```

Make sure you hit Ctrl+Shift+Enter. What it does is it only extracts values corresponding to the specific product using the if statement, min then finds the minimum value out of that range.

Same applies to the SMALL function, it can take a range but we must filter that range using the IF function to get only the columns we want for that product, this also requires to be an array formula by entering it with Ctrl+Shift+Enter

```
=SMALL(IF($B$2:$M$2=N$2,$B3:$M3),2)
```

Comment: Thank you so much... Was really in need of the solution... The solution is bang on.

Answer (score 2):

Another option in non-array formula solution

Assume your data put in `A1:P5`

"Minimum quote" in `K3`, copied across to M3, and all copied down :

```
=AGGREGATE(15,6,$B3:$J3/($B$2:$J$2=K$2),1)
```

"2nd lowest quote" in `N3`, copied across to P3, and all copied down :

```
=AGGREGATE(15,6,$B3:$J3/($B$2:$J$2=N$2),2)
```